# How to get the IIS site Physical path and the Binding details using power shell script

Tags: powershell

I wrote a PS script where in it will export all the IIS site details and App-pool details to the Excel sheet, but when i use the command **Get-IISSite** the physical path and the binding details are not displaying in the output console as below, the code is as follows, please help me to fix the issue which i am facing to export the IIS site and app-pool details

**Code**

```
#Clearing the Console host in PS
Clear-Host

$Computers = Get-Content "C:\TEMP\servers.txt" 

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers -ScriptBlock {
    # Changed to newer IISAdministration Module to match Get-IISAppPool
    $Websites = Get-IISSite

    foreach ($Website in $Websites) {

        $AppPool = Get-IISAppPool -Name $Website.Applications[0].ApplicationPoolName

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Website_Name                  = $Website.Name
            Website_Id                    = $Website.Id -join ';'
            Website_State                 = $Website.State -join ';'
            Website_PhysicalPath          = Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\Sites\P #$Website.PhysicalPath -join ';'
            Website_Bindings              = $Website.Bindings.Collection -join ';'
            Website_Attributes            = ($Website.Attributes | ForEach-Object { $_.name + "=" + $_.value }) -join ';'
            AppPool_Name                  = $AppPool.Name -join';'
            AppPool_State                 = $AppPool.State -join ';'
            AppPool_ManagedRuntimeVersion = $AppPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion -join ';'
            AppPool_ManagedPipelineMode   = $AppPool.ManagedPipelineMode -join ';'
            AppPool_StartMode             = $AppPool.StartMode -join ';'
        }
    }
} | Export-Excel -Path C:\users\$env:username\documents\Site_App-pool_Details.xlsx -AutoSize -BoldTopRow
```

**OutPut**

```
Website_Name                  : Test
Website_Id                    : 2
Website_State                 : Started
Website_PhysicalPath          : 
Website_Bindings              : 
Website_Attributes            : name=Test;id=2;serverAutoStart=False;state=
                                1
AppPool_Name                  : Test
AppPool_State                 : Started
AppPool_ManagedRuntimeVersion : v4.0
AppPool_ManagedPipelineMode   : Integrated
AppPool_StartMode             : OnDemand
PSComputerName                : AAA
RunspaceId                    : 47d..

When i use the command **Get-Website** i will get all the output details of the IIS site but not the IIS App-pool details the code is a below

Output
Website_Name                  : Test
Website_Id                    : 2
Website_State                 : Started
Website_PhysicalPath          : C:\AAA
Website_Bindings              : http 10.62.:Test.com
Website_Attributes            : name=Test;id=2;serverAutoStart=False;state=
                                1
AppPool_Name                  : 
AppPool_State                 : 
AppPool_ManagedRuntimeVersion : 
AppPool_ManagedPipelineMode   : 
AppPool_StartMode             : 
PSComputerName                : AAA
RunspaceId                    : 15d..
```

Please help me like how to get all the IIS site and App-pool details by using any of the command from both (Get-Website or Get-WebSite)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you are using `Get-Website`, then the apppool should be `Get-IISAppPool -Name $Website.ApplicationPool`

Answer (score 1):

you have a weird comment in your code on that line which breaks it; but, try this:

```
Get-Item IIS:\Sites\$Website | Select-Object -ExpandProperty physicalPath
```

instead of

```
Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\Sites\$Website.PhysicalPath
```

for bindings:

```
$Website.Bindings.bindingInformation
```

instead of

```
$Website.Bindings.Collection
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following with `Get-Website` and `Get-IISAppPool`.

```
$Websites = Get-Website

foreach ($Website in $Websites) {

    $AppPool = Get-IISAppPool -Name $Website.ApplicationPool

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Website_Name                  = $Website.Name
        Website_Id                    = $Website.Id -join ';'
        Website_State                 = $Website.State -join ';'
        Website_PhysicalPath          = $Website.PhysicalPath
        Website_Bindings              = $Website.Bindings.Collection -join ';'
        Website_Attributes            = ($Website.Attributes | ForEach-Object { $_.name + "=" + $_.value }) -join ';'
        AppPool_Name                  = $AppPool.Name -join';'
        AppPool_State                 = $AppPool.State -join ';'
        AppPool_ManagedRuntimeVersion = $AppPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion -join ';'
        AppPool_ManagedPipelineMode   = $AppPool.ManagedPipelineMode -join ';'
        AppPool_StartMode             = $AppPool.StartMode -join ';'
    }
}
```

**Sample Output**

> ```
> Website_Name                  : Default Web Site
> Website_Id                    : 1
> Website_State                 : Started
> Website_PhysicalPath          : %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot
> Website_Bindings              : net.msmq localhost;msmq.formatname localhost;net.tcp 808:*;net.pipe *;http *:80:
> Website_Attributes            : name=Default Web Site;id=1;serverAutoStart=True;state=1
> AppPool_Name                  : DefaultAppPool
> AppPool_State                 : Started
> AppPool_ManagedRuntimeVersion : v4.0
> AppPool_ManagedPipelineMode   : Integrated
> AppPool_StartMode             : OnDemand
> ```

**Changes Made**

1. Use `Get-Website` to populate `$Websites`.
2. Pass `$Website.ApplicationPool` into the `-Name` parameter of `Get-IISAppPool`.
3. Set `Website_PhysicalPath` to `$Website.PhysicalPath`

Comment: Thanks for the help i got the exact output like how i need.

I need one more help please, can you please tell me like how can i get the color for the full header of the excel file in my script